# Swift 4 / Xcode - Display string value(s) from an Array/Struct to CATextLayer()

Tags: ios, swift, catextlayer

I am struggling to get this to work.

I have a `struct` in place to help to pass data through each `.swift`file. (Only have one view controller).

This is my `Message` class where both the text layer and the shapes (`SCNBox`) are called/created.

```
struct MessagesStruct {
    var text = String()
}

class Message: SCNNode {

    public var messageDataArray = [MessagesStruct]()
    public let textArray = Array<MessagesStruct>()
    public let textLayer = CATextLayer()


    override init() {
         super.init()
        let layer = CALayer()
        layer.backgroundColor = UIColor.black.withAlphaComponent(0.8).cgColor

        textLayer.frame = layer.bounds
        textLayer.fontSize = 30


 //   generateTextOnLabel() -- Don't work

        var data = String()
        for each in Array<MessagesStruct>() {
            data = each.text

        }
        textLayer.string = data

        textLayer.alignmentMode = kCAAlignmentCenter
        textLayer.foregroundColor = UIColor.white.cgColor
        textLayer.display()
        layer.addSublayer(textLayer)
        textLayer.layoutIfNeeded()
        textLayer.isWrapped = true
        layer.layoutIfNeeded()



        let box = SCNBox(width: 8.5, height: 1.25, length: 0.01, chamferRadius: 4)
        box.firstMaterial?.locksAmbientWithDiffuse = true
        self.geometry = box
        let shape = SCNPhysicsShape(geometry: box, options: nil)
        self.physicsBody = SCNPhysicsBody(type: .static, shape: shape)
        self.physicsBody?.isAffectedByGravity = false
        self.geometry?.firstMaterial?.diffuse.contents = layer

    }
    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }


    func generateTextOnLabel() {
        var dataToDisplay = String()
        for data in textArray {
            dataToDisplay = data.text
        }

        textLayer.string = dataToDisplay
    }
}
```

This is my `ViewControler` class, I have taken out all the irrelevant lines of code e.g. IBOulets etc.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, ARSCNViewDelegate, UITextViewDelegate {
    @IBOutlet var sceneView: ARSCNView!
    @IBOutlet var generateNotesButton: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet var addNotesButton: UIButton!


    @IBOutlet var saveButton: UIButton!

    var messagesArray: [MessagesStruct] = []

    var refToMessages = Message()


        @IBAction func saveButton_TouchUpInside(_ sender: Any) {
    var notes = MessageStruct()
    notes.text = textView.text
    messagesArray.append(notes)

}


    @IBAction func generateNotes_TouchUpInside(_ sender: Any) {

        for _ in 0...notesArray.count {
        let messageNode = Message()
           refToMessages.messagesDataArray.append(contentsOf: messagesArray)
            sceneView.scene.rootNode.addChildNode(messageNode)
        }
    }
```

As far as I am aware, the data is passed through as I have used the `print` command. However, the text layer is always blank. When printing to console I can retrieve the values in the array and the length using the `.count` method. But there is an issue of trying to get the data in the array to display. I have tried to utilise an array and even a struct but nothing works. Only time the label displays any text is when I write something like this:

`textLayer.string = "Hello World"`

As you can guess, the label will appear with the message `Hello World`.

Can anyone help me to overcome this small issue? I have never used `CATextLayer()` and I'm treating it almost like a `UILabel` so this may be my downfall. But I am running out of options and just cannot get this to work.

Thank you.

Comment: Probably need += data but why not just use joined() to get the string from the string array

Comment: @agibson007 Thank you for your answer. I'll try and implement and let you know if it works. And I never thought about it.

Comment: After looking I did not see it was an array of struct. you probably want let combinedString = messagesDataArray.map({return 0$.text}). Typed on mobile so probably wrong but close